# How to connect to phone and send files & chat messages via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, file-transfer

I am creating a `Android Application` that will have a `Menu` containing two options:

- `Chat` via `Bluetooth`.
- `Transfer Files` via `Bluetooth`.
- `Config` containing controls to turn `Bluetooth` `OFF` and `ON`, and `Visibility` `OFF` and `ON`

**1)** I have made the Chat and now it works, but the method that i have used i dont think so that is totally right.

I have a button "Server" and another button "Client" one mobile phone needs to click server and wait to the other click client and connect to it.

There is another way to Chat instead of this way?

I can provide code as possible, but i dont know what part of code that i need to provide, because i cant post all the whole code here, can i? its too broad.

**2)** I want to Transfer Files using the samme connection that i used on the Chat.

Can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [the android bluetooth tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices) can help you

And this tutorial say how you can send messages and files between devices:
[Bluetooth Data Transfer](http://manojprasaddevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/02/bluetooth-data-transfer-example.html)

But, basically:
You need add this permission to your manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

And your on create event could looks like: (But all the codes are in the tutorial)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txDevice);
MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(!ba.isEnabled()){
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivity(intent);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to you man, it seems to work, i was going to test it now but i dont know how my eclipse stopped from working i cannot open it anymore o.o

Comment: Problem with eclipse done, now i just did test your code and it works, but i want to know a thing: and to `DEACTIVATE` `Bluetooth` what `ACTION`?

Comment: The answer of @Abhishek V is better on this plus of enabling, disabling bluetooth, but the tutorial is great :D

Answer (score 1):

Google has provided a sample app to demonstrate the Bluetooth chat. You can refer it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat

It is fully functional bluetooth chat application.

And to activate and deactivate bluetooth you can use this code

```
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
 if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      //deatctivate bluetooth
     mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
  } 
    //Activate bluetooth
  mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

Comment: Thanks man, your code works perfectly, but you forget a thing, the application manifest need to have the following permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`